# Is azure API Management consumption based?

Tags: api, azure

To Devs,

I am using Azure Functions in a consumption based mode but if I use the API Management Services, I then get nailed with a fixed cost. Is there a way to set up API Management in consumption mode?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the API management is billed per hour rather than on a consumption basis and there is no way of changing this

Comment: Docs and Portal on create appeared to indicate this, Thanks, Marc